# Read XML with jquery/javascript every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have a html

index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Facebook</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../xdata/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Tasks (<span id="tasks">0</span>)
    Messages (<span id="messages">0</span>)
    Notifications (<span id="notifications">0</span>)


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pagetitle = document.title;
    document.title = pagetitle+' NEW NOTIFICATON';
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and a xml file

page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page tasks="1" messages="3" notifications="3"/>
```

How do i make that every 5 seconds `index.html` to read `page.xml` and modify the title like in faceboook ("(1) Facebook") and also modify tasks, messages, notifications ...

I'm having problems at reading the xml. If anyone can help me?

PS - I prefer jQuery ... but JavaScript works as well

Comment: Use `setInterval` and set the time to 5 seconds. Then call various functions within it that will do what you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following was done in jquery, though you have a slight error with your xml file that lead to parsing issues.

Assuming your xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <page tasks="1" messages="3" notifications="3"/>
</data>
```

The following code will modify the page accordingly, using jquery of course:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function get_info() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "page.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            complete: function(doc) {
                var tasks = $(doc.responseText).find("page").attr("tasks");
                var msgs = $(doc.responseText).find("page").attr("messages");
                var notes = $(doc.responseText).find("page").attr("notifications");
                if (tasks != $('#tasks').text() ||
                    msgs != $('#messages').text() ||
                    notes != $('#notifications').text()) {
                    document.title = "Facebook" + ' NEW NOTIFICATON';
                }
                $('#tasks').text(tasks);
                $('#messages').text(msgs);
                $('#notifications').text(notes);
            }
        });

    }
    setInterval(function() {
        get_info();
    }, 5000);
});
```

I spent some time developing this, and I know for a fact it works.

Comment: @RowMinds I tested it on chrome, you want me to show you a screen shot of it working?  What error are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting an error, just won't work, do you have an debug idea? or is just my pc?

Comment: @RowMinds So you tested this on your local machine?  Are you using something like xampp or wamp?  What server package are you using?

Comment: and also, my page.xml is in ../../page.xml , how it's recommended , the "../../path/" way or the "http://www ..." way??

Comment: @RowMinds Is that path in relation to your host's tree, or the tree of your url?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13697/discussion-between-daedalus-and-row-minds)

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic inside of a setTimeout method call:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('I am displayed after 3 seconds!');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Do *NOT* pass strings to `setTimeout`!  It uses `eval`.  Pass functions.  `setTimeout(function(){alert('I am displayed after 3 seconds!');}, 3000);`

Comment: Sorry, got lazy and grabbed the example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp.  As noted, use anonymous functions :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var tid = setTimeout(function_name, 5000);

function function_name() {
  // do some stuff...
  tid = setTimeout(function_name, 5000); // repeat
}
function abortTimer() { // to stop the timer
  clearTimeout(tid);
}
```

Comment: should be `setInterval(function_name, 5000);`

Comment: var increment = 2;
  function fname()
  {
   increment = increment + 1;
   alert('qq');
  }
  

  setInterval(fname,1000);

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this:
    (document).ready(function() {
        function getPage() {
           var page= $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "page.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                async : false,
            }).responseXML;
       $(page).find('page').each(function(){
         var tasks = $(this).attr("tasks");
         var msgs = $(this).attr("messages");
         var notes = $(this).attr("notifications");
         $('#tasks').html(tasks);
         $('#messages').html(msgs);
         $('#notifications').html(notes);
      });
   }
});
    setInterval(getPage,5000);
```