# Displaying XML data in HTML with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Am trying to show data from an XML file using jQuery and although I have the correct amount of data it is repeating.
js:

```
    $(function(){var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><sports file_date="2014-02-08T08:30:11.207">  <sport id="1" name="Football"><event id="3" name="Eng. Premier League"><match id="670358" live_id="91583" name="Liverpool - Arsenal" start_date="2014-02-08T12:45:00" streaming="0"><bets><bet code="Ftb_Mr3" id="10178143" name="Match Result"><choice id="75726090" name="%1%" odd="2.10"/><choice id="75726093" name="Draw" odd="3.40"/><choice id="75726096" name="%2%" odd="3.30"/></bet></bets></match></event></sport></sports>';

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); 

    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var $match = $xml.find("match");
    var $odds = $match.find("choice");

    var game = $match.attr('name'),
        odd = $odds.attr('odd');

    $("#title").append(game);
    $odds.each(function(){
        $("#odds" ).append('<li>' +odd+ '</li>');

    });
});
```

You can see this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6XcHW/

Any suggestions would be very helpful I also want this data (will be an external xml file) to be checked every 30 seconds using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

http://jsfiddle.net/6XcHW/3/

```
$(function(){
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><sports file_date="2014-02-08T08:30:11.207">   <sport id="1" name="Football"><event id="3" name="Eng. Premier League"><match id="670358" live_id="91583" name="Liverpool - Arsenal" start_date="2014-02-08T12:45:00" streaming="0"><bets><bet code="Ftb_Mr3" id="10178143" name="Match Result"><choice id="75726090" name="%1%" odd="2.10"/><choice id="75726093" name="Draw" odd="3.40"/><choice id="75726096" name="%2%" odd="3.30"/></bet></bets></match></event></sport></sports>';

    //Parse the givn XML
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); 

var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var $match = $xml.find("match");
    var $odds = $match.find("choice");



    var game = $match.attr('name');


    $("#title").append(game);
            $odds.each(function(){
                odd = $(this).attr('odd');

    $("#odds" ).append('<li>' +odd+ '</li>');

    });
});
```

So, odd var is created 'on the fly', inside loop, and then there is no repeating (in your code, just first match was repeated).

Comment: Thanks I knew it would be somehting obvious any suggestions to get the ajax working?

Comment: @wroughtec, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421373/read-xml-with-jquery-javascript-every-5-seconds. This should help...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you had each object but not the value in the attribute, the code should like this

```
$odds.each(function(){
    $("#odds" ).append('<li>' + $(this).attr('odd') + '</li>');  
});
```

Hope this helps :)